# Parse.com sync data from an account to another

Tags: parse-platform, migration

I'm trying to sync the data between parse.com account (which is production) to another parse.com (which is development). Any ideas? I have found a way to export the production into CSV, but I can't import it with the relations and pointers.

Comment: import button seems been removed. You cannot import them.

Answer (score 0):

Due to import function seems not supported, you should try to duplicate your  mongodb from prod to dev.

First, following the migration guide(db part) point the db by your uri. Second, duplicate the prod db to another db, and get another uri. Third, create new Parse APP with this uri.